How to accurately insert hyperlink/hypertarget pairs in a beamer presentation?
Based on several Q&A on hyperlink/hypertarget pairs, I am trying to design beamer presentations with overlays, exercises and solutions. The solutions are located at the end of the document, in the same order as the exercises. I want to automate the numbering of exercises and solutions, so I am using two counters:
\newcounter{exercise}\resetcounteronoverlays{exercise}
\newcounter{solution}\resetcounteronoverlays{solution}

I also want to automate the insertion of hyperlink/hypertarget pairs to navigate back and forth during the presentation. In the last slide of each exercise there should be a clickable button that links to the first slide of the solution, and in the last slide of each solution there should be a clickable button that links back to the last slide of the exercise. During the lecture I:

uncover the exercise, slide after slide, until the to-solution button is visible,
click on the to-solution button to jump to the first slide of the solution,
uncover the solution, slide after slide, until the to-exercise button is visible,
click on the to-exercise button to jump back to the last slide of the exercise,
continue the lecture with the first slide after the exercise.

As the text of exercises and solutions can be short or long I decided to split all this in 4 commands, plus an intermediate (\overlaynumber) to get the current slide number:
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@minimum}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\newex}{\stepcounter{exercise}{Ex. \theexercise{}: }}
\newcommand*{\tosol}{\hfill{}\hyperlink<\overlaynumber{}>{sol-\theexercise}{\hypertarget{ex-\theexercise}{\beamergotobutton{}}}}
\newcommand*{\newsol}{\stepcounter{solution}\hypertarget<\overlaynumber{}>{sol-\thesolution}{}{Ex. \thesolution{}: }}
\newcommand*{\toex}{\hfill{}\hyperlink<\overlaynumber{}>{ex-\thesolution}{\beamergotobutton{}}}

\newex increments and typesets the exercise counter. \tosol inserts the sol-N hyperlink and the ex-N return hypertarget. \newsol increments and typesets the solution counter, and inserts the sol-N hypertarget. Finally, \toex inserts the ex-N return hyperlink.
Everything works as expected (exercises 1 and 2 of the example below) as long as I don't use my commands in block or frame titles.
When a solution needs a complete block or more (as in exercise 3 of the example below) and I put the \newsol command at the beginning of the block title, the link to the solution does not point to the slide where the block is first shown but to the first slide of its frame.
When a solution needs a complete frame or more (as in exercise 4 of the example below) and I put the \newsol command at the beginning of the frame title, the link to the solution points to the last slide of the frame instead of the first. And the return to exercise link is also wrong: it points to the slide before that of the question.
I suspect that my counters are not incremented at the right compilation time and/or my \overlaynumber command does not behave as I would like when used in block or frame titles.
Is there a way to obtain the right hyperlink/hypertarget behavior even in block or frame titles?
MWE:
\PassOptionsToPackage{unicode}{hyperref}
\documentclass{beamer}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty{}
\newcounter{exercise}\resetcounteronoverlays{exercise}
\newcounter{solution}\resetcounteronoverlays{solution}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\overlaynumber}{\number\beamer@minimum}
\makeatother
\newcommand*{\newex}{\stepcounter{exercise}{Ex. \theexercise{}: }}
\newcommand*{\tosol}{\hfill{}\hyperlink<\overlaynumber{}>{sol-\theexercise}{\hypertarget{ex-\theexercise}{\beamergotobutton{}}}}
\newcommand*{\newsol}{\stepcounter{solution}\hypertarget<\overlaynumber{}>{sol-\thesolution}{}{Ex. \thesolution{}: }}
\newcommand*{\toex}{\hfill{}\hyperlink<\overlaynumber{}>{ex-\thesolution}{\beamergotobutton{}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame one}
  \begin{block}{Block one}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item \newex{}How many prime numbers less than 10?\tosol{}
      \item \newex{}How many even prime numbers?\tosol{}
      \item \newex{}Sum of prime numbers less than 10?\tosol{}
      \item \newex{}Product of prime numbers less than 10?\tosol{}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame two}
  \begin{block}{Block one}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item \newsol{}4 (2, 3, 5 and 7)\toex{}
      \item \newsol{}1 (2)\toex{}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}

  \onslide<+->
  \begin{block}{\newsol{}Sum of prime numbers less than 10?}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item $2 + 3 + 5 + 7 = 17$
      \item Note: 17 is prime\toex{}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{\newsol{}Product of prime numbers less than 10?}
  \begin{block}{Block one}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
      \item $2 \times 3 \times 5 \times 7 = 210$
      \item Note: 210 is not prime
      \item Note: 210 is even\toex{}
    \end{itemize}
  \end{block}
\end{frame}

\end{document}


I'd probably place the exercise and solution in the same frame and use \againframe to show the solution at the end

Well the problem is your \overlaynumber. I don't know where you got \beamer@minimum from but it clearly doesn't do what you expect it to do,  counting slides, and even if it would do that: you are splitting the solutions over two frames, and so the solutions have other slide numbers than the exercises.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Interesting suggestion, thanks. I will experiment with \againframe and see what I can get from that. Not sure how it can solve the automated insertion of hyperlink/hypertarget pairs, though. The main benefit of what I try to achieve is to avoid manual management of slide numbers. Do you have suggestions? Moreover, when several exercises fit on the same frame (like in my example), I would like to navigate back and forth several times between the same exercise slide and one or several solution slides. Would it be possible with \againframe?

@UlrikeFischer Yes, the problem may be with my \overlaynumber command. I got it from the beamer sources (beamerbasedecode.sty). But I have probably missed something. Not sure I understand your second point. Of course, exercises and solutions have different slide numbers, but I am using hyperlink/hypertarget pairs with names generated from the exercise/solution numbers. Why do you think that different slide numbers is an obstacle?

you are using links and targets which also include the overlay number.

Not really, the overlay specification just decides on which slide they are visible/active, not the destination of the link. And this works nicely. The link target is only ex-N or sol-N where N is the exercise or solution number. No more, not something computed from the overlay number.

I case you don't know how overlays work, the hyperlink andhypertarget commands are "overlay-aware". This means that \hyperlink<4>{target}{text}, for instance, creates a link to target, with text text, on slide number 4. The 4 has nothing to do with the target, it's just a slide number in the frame of the hyperlink. Same for \hypertarget<5>{target}{text}: it creates a target target with text text on slide number 5 in the frame of the hypertarget. The 5 has nothing to do with the target itself.

The effect of the overlay specifications is only that the links or targets are active/visible only on the specified slide(s). They have no impact on the target or on the link themselves.
